# Applying initcwn/ initrwnd to routes from DHCP

Tags: networking, linux-networking, dhcp, systemd, systemd-networkd

I am using Amazon Linux 2023 (which is based on Fedora and uses systemd-networkd for DHCP).

`ip route show` shows routes like `default via 10.0.0.1 dev enX0 proto dhcp src 10.0.0.211 metric 1024`

I would like to have "initcwnd 50 initrwnd 50" applied to that route. I can do this via `ip route change`. This works until my lease expires. When DHCP renews it, I end up with a second (duplicate) default route.

I can create a conf file in `/etc/systemd/network/` with contents like

```
[Match]
Name=enX0

[Network]
DHCP=yes

[Route]
Gateway=10.0.0.1
InitialCongestionWindow=50
InitialAdvertisedReceiveWindow=50
Metric=100
```

, but this still ends up duplicating routes or forcing me to hardcode things about them that should be configured dynamically with DHCP.

I would like my system to get routes and configuration from DHCP like it does today, but to keep my initcwn/ initrwnd values applied at all times. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you could run a script after DHCP is renewed, first create a network dispatcher script directory

```
sudo mkdir -p /etc/systemd/network
```

then we will create a costum script to modify the route after DHCP renewal, create this file

```
sudo nano /etc/systemd/network/10-custom-route-settings.network
```

then add this inside

```
[Match]
Name=enX0

[Network]
DHCP=yes

[DHCP]
RouteMetric=100

[Route]
Gateway=_dhcp4_gateway
Destination=default
InitialCongestionWindow=50
InitialAdvertisedReceiveWindow=50
```

save and close then finaly we can restart `systemd-networkd`

```
sudo systemctl restart systemd-networkd
```

Comment: Thanks @Saxtheowl .  Are you sure that script location is relevant for systemd-networkd ? I'm looking into and it seems like it might be for NetworkManager. (FWIW, I tried to upvote you, but apparently I don't have enough reputation to do so)

Comment: yup, I modified my answer, you can just accept it if it fixed your problem.